# Delay website re-direct on form submission

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using Cognito Forms as an input mask to collect data for use in a company wiki. Through a mechanism using Zapier and Dropbox, the collected data is uploaded to the site as a text file. Once the form is submitted, the form redirects the user to the location of the file in the wiki.

Problem is that the mechanism takes a few seconds to upload the text file, and the user is directed to a page that does not exist yet. Refreshing the page helps, but it would be ideal if there were some way to adjust the script, so that the re-direct kicks in a few seconds after the form has been submitted.

I am embedding the form in the wiki itself using the seamless script.

Anyone able to help out?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the redirect waited a few seconds, that wouldn't guarantee that the users would never get errors (although it might decrease the frequency).  It seems like a better solution would be to redirect to a page which has a function to check for the existence of the file and then do another redirect from there to actually take them to the file.